# Multi Device Bluetooth keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboards, bluetooth, mice

I am looking for a keyboard (and optionally a mouse) that is Bluetooth-enabled and backlit and can switch between different Bluetooth devices (pc and tablet/phone).

Comment: Do you have a specific need for this, such as gaming? If it is for day to day work this might be similar to what you are looking for: https://www.amazon.com/Coastacloud-Wireless-Bluetooth-Universal-Rechargeable/dp/B07PLQ4QFL/ref=sr_1_1?creative=9325&creativeASIN=B0148XXR22&keywords=Backlit+Bluetooth+Keyboard%2C+TeckNet+Universal+Ultra-Slim+Portable+Illuminated+7-Colors+Adjustable+Bluetooth+Wireless+Keyboard&linkCode=gs3&linkId=d1f79fa0137a957add41fb7d0adfbf11&qid=1579889761&sr=8-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following Logitech Keyboards with their "Easy-Switch" technology will allow you to switch between multiple devices via Bluetooth. They have three buttons or a 3-way dial to switch instantly between up to three devices.

I personally use the tenkeyless (TKL) Logitech K480 at work since it can switch between 3 devices and has a tray for my cell phone. If you'd like a numberpad, the Logitech K780 is a good choice. Here are all of the keyboards that Logitech sells direct-to-consumer that contain the [Easy-Switch technology](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards?filters=3948,3949,3959). For some reason the K480 is on its own page [here](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/multi-device-keyboard-k480). Most Logitech keyboards can also be purchased online or at Brick-and-Mortar stores such as Amazon, Best Buy, Micro Center, Newegg, Staples, Walmart, ect.

As far as mice go, Logitech continues with their MX Anywhere lineup. Any of the MX 2S or 3 series mice will have Easy-Switch. They also let you copy files on one PC and paste them on another which is a nice feature to have. You may find the MX Anywhere 2S [here](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-anywhere-2s-flow?crid=7).

Comment: Great recommendation! I ended up buying the K380 keyboard and Logitech Marathon mouse. I love it!

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth itself is single master multiple slave. Which means that you cannot bind a device to multiple hosts simultaneously. You would have to reconnect/rebind your keyboard every time you want to switch the master. There is no way around it.

Comment: I think they simply want it to be able to connect to different platforms (Android, PC, etc.) even if it has to be paired each time. And Single Master isn't true for all devices. Bluetooth speakers/headphones for example can work with multiple devices without need for new pairing.